# How to get coordinates of each cube forming a wall

Tags: java, opengl

I am implementing collisions in 3D room which I am coding. I have a Labyrinth class where I set the border of the room to true in a list to keep information about where the cubes will be drawed:

```
public class Labyrinth {

private boolean [][] wall = new boolean[21][21];
private boolean [][] ground = new boolean[21][21];

public Labyrinth() {
    super(); 
    this.initializeMap();

}   


private void initializeMap() {

    // inicializace zdí okolo celého bludiště
    for(int x = 0; x < 21; x=x+2) {
        wall[x][0] = true;
        wall[x][20] = true;
    }

    for(int y = 0; y < 21; y=y+2) {
        wall[0][y] = true;
        wall[20][y] = true;
    }
```

In the rendering class I draw the cube wherever the wall is set to true. It looks like this:

```
/ render labyrintu
    for(int i=0; i<21; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<21; j++) {
            if(labyrinth.getWall()[i][j]) {                   
                  gl.glTranslatef((float)i, 0f, (float)j);
                  wallTexture.enable(gl);
                  wallTexture.bind(gl);
                  gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);

                // Front Face
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

                  // Back Face
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

                  // Top Face
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

                  // Bottom Face
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

                  // Right face
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

                  // Left Face
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                  gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
                  gl.glEnd();
                  gl.glTranslatef((float)-i, 0f, (float)-j);

            }                 
        }
    }
```

What I want to do now is to implement collisions using AABB algorithm. For that I need to know the x,y,z coordinates of every cube which I draw. Then I could simply compare them with coordinates of camera. I want to do it like this:

```
    public static boolean checkCollision(ObjectBox a, ObjectBox b){
{
   //check the X axis
   if(Math.abs(a.getX() - b.getX()) < a.getSizeX() + b.getSizeX())
   {
      //check the Y axis
      if(Math.abs(a.getY() - b.getY()) < a.getSizeY() + b.getSizeY())
      {
          //check the Z axis
          if(Math.abs(a.getZ() - b.getZ()) < a.getSizeZ() + b.getSizeZ())
          {
             return true;
          }
      }
   }

   return false;
}
```

How can I get those coordinates of every single cube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your rendering code, looks like your AABB's are cubes of side length 2 centered on `(i, 0, j)` where `i, j` are integers. Therefore for an AABB indexed by `i, j`:

- `getX()` should return `i`; similarly for Y and Z
- `getSizeX()` should return 1 (half of the side length); *same* for Y and Z

Comment: exactly what i needed to know!